# Grabbing the current URL from browser not working. Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

I currently have a script that gets the token for discord:

```
document.getElementById("ImportantUpgrade").addEventListener("click", myFunction);


function myFunction() {
   const URL = "Random URL";
   window.location.href = URL;
   
   while(true)
   {
      if(URL != window.location.href)
      {
         console.log( window.location.href);
      }
   }

}
```

```
Example:

User gets loaded to: MYURL.com, my code checks to see when a change occurs. 

User hits the authorize button, then gets taken to MYURl.com/token, I try to grab this url, but the JS does not detect a url change.
```

Basically, the user gets taken to a url where they have to authorize discord. Then once they authorize, the discord token gets placed in the browser url. The problem is, when the user hits the button and get taken to a new url, my program does not detect that new url. It still thinks im on the original url. I am trying to log the url with the token, but it does not seem to detect that url change when I keep grabbing the URL. What is going on?

Comment: In your code, the condition always evaluates to false. That's why it does not console.log. Try to console.log before you hit the while loop for debugging.

Comment: @H.Udara How does i make it detect that URL change? You did not answer my question.

Comment: It probably detects the URL change. You are not hitting the console.log line because of the condition which is always false.

Comment: If I keep printing the URL in a while loop and the url changes, it does not print out the current URL. @H.Udara

Comment: After you execute window.location.href the browser will probably refresh and it will not even execute the rest of the code in your method.

Comment: @H.Udara No. It just does not detect that URL change.

Comment: When you do this, window.location.href, does the URL in the address bar change?

Comment: What you are trying is not possible, after sending the user to the new URL your script will stop running, sinds the user is send to a new page and is not anymore on your page. I expect you are  try to do a oAuth flow and that case the callback URL will contain a token ( or code ). instead of checking if the URL has changed, you should check if the URL contains the token

Comment: @VictorPerez can i make the script keep running even after redirect?

Comment: No you can't, what you can do is onload check of the URL contains the token.

Comment: @VictorPerez Mind providing the code for this. Thank you.

Comment: Look into Ajax, it will be very helpful. Ajax will let you communicate with a server without having to reload the entire page. [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are trying to do oAuth? Because in that case you better off by using a library because after you have the token, you need to store and maybe refresh the token.

Comment: @VictorPerez Yes! Thats exactly what I am doing.

Comment: @tagog97383 there is good example on this page https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#putting-it-together